# How to link Visual Studio 2008 to Microsoft Excel  

Tags: c#

I want know how to take information from a `GridView` and show it in Excel as a chart. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You save its datasource -

```
datasetname.WriteXml(filename);
```

Excel can read XML files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate an Excel workbook.

Maybe [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B302096&x=16&y=8) will provide a good entry point for your task. What is needed is VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) to perform Excel-Automation tasks.